# Iterate a jSON array and convert the values to percentage

Tags: arrays, json

I have a json array .

{1: 2500, 2: 3000, 3: 3000, 4: 2500, 5: 5000, 6: 3000}

Here 5000 is the maximum value and it is 100%.

I want to iterate this array and form another javascript array 
{50%, 60%, 60%, 50%, 100%, 60%}

How can i do this efficiently in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Just select max element from the array and use the built in map function to produce another array with percentages.

```
var yourArray = [2500, 3000, 3000, 2500, 5000, 3000];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, yourArray); // picks out 5000
var percents = yourArray.map(n => n/max * 100.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, these are actually not arrays. In JS, arrays have square brackets and objects (like what you have) have curly braces. When you see something like this: `{name: "dave", age: "30"}`, this is an object whereby `name` and `age` are properties. Arrays can't have properties in JS. So an array might look like this: `["dave", 32]`. Also, you can't have numbers as properties.

`var x = {1: 2500} // this wont work`

the final output that you want will also not work as you described an object (when you used the curlies) and what you'll want is an array. So what you'll probably want is more like converting an array `[2500, 3000, 3000, 2500, 5000, 3000]` to an array that looks like `["50%", "60%", "60%", "50%", "100%", "60%"]`

Notice that in the first array, the values were true numbers (not in quotes) but the end result array the values will be strings since we have the percent sign

You can use a map function to do this. This code "maps" each item of an array to a function. Whatever the function returns will replace the original item in the original array

```
var originalArray = [3000, 5000];
var newArray = originalArray.map(function(item) {
  return ((item / 5000) * 100) + '%'
})

console.log(newArray)
```