# JSON values convert to percentage

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Using typescript, what is the best way to convert JSON value to a percentage?

JSON

```
{
  "outer_attribute": {
    "brands": [
    {
        "brand_names": "brand6",
        "Vertical": "Automotive",
        "customer_visit_ratio": "0.03935382863419896"
    },
    {
        "brand_names": "brand5",
        "Vertical": "Automotive",
        "customer_visit_ratio": "0.00935382863419896"
    },
    {
        "brand_names": "brand12",
        "Vertical": "Automotive",
        "customer_visit_ratio": "0.30935382863419896"
    }
    ]
}
}
```

I need to convert the values of "customer_visit_ratio" to percentage values. Tried .map but didn't work.

Comment: Can work.. what did you try? Please note, these are strings.. you’d need to convert to floats first..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474069/iterate-a-json-array-and-convert-the-values-to-percentage

Tried this @MikeOne

Comment: @Abhijeetc50 see my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map` like this:

```js
var passengers = {
  "outer_attribute": {
    "brands": [
    {
        "brand_names": "brand6",
        "Vertical": "Automotive",
        "customer_visit_ratio": "0.03935382863419896"
    },
    {
        "brand_names": "brand5",
        "Vertical": "Automotive",
        "customer_visit_ratio": "0.00935382863419896"
    },
    {
        "brand_names": "brand12",
        "Vertical": "Automotive",
        "customer_visit_ratio": "0.30935382863419896"
    }
    ]
}
};


var modifiedBrands = passengers.outer_attribute.brands.map(function(arrayCell){
  return {...arrayCell, customer_visit_ratio: (arrayCell.customer_visit_ratio* 100).toFixed(2)};
});
passengers.outer_attribute.brands = modifiedBrands ;
console.log('passengers', passengers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
this.data.outer_attribute.brands = this.data.outer_attribute.brands.map(
  item => ({...item, percent : (Number(item.customer_visit_ratio) * 100).toFixed(2)})
);
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psuque?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine but it adds a new key-value pair the JSON.

Comment: This can be done without adding a new key as well, check the modified demo